# Extend ListActivity and BaseGameActivity

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to extend both ListActivity and [BaseGameActivity](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/basegameutils/BaseGameActivity.java)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in Java you cannot extend multiple base classes.  You can implement multiple interfaces, but that's it.

You don't really need ListActivity though.  The total amount of code it adds is about 6 lines.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please write those lines from ListActivity that I need to add in BaseGameActivity?